# How to change the field value in update form in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my update form, I want to show the original value rather than it's `id`. Below is my `_form`.

```
<div class="mdc-meter-config-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'con','options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
<label class="control-label">Select Meters</label><br />
<input type="text" id="the-mter-id" class="form-control col-md-12" value="<?=$model->meter_id?>" />
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="selected_mters_container"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<br/>

<?= $form->field($model, 'p_id')->dropDownList([''=>'Please Select']+\common\models\MdcProtocol::toArrayList()) ?>


<?= $form->field($model, 'time')
    ->dropDownList([''=>'Please Select','5' => '5', '10' => '10', '15' => '15','20'=>'20'])->label("Set Time (in seconds)") ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

[image]

In above view I want to change the `2` value to its actual one which is `4A60193390662`

Comment: Explain your question more clear with examples of output.

Comment: In your view there is not 0  ..  but  .. 02-ytibus .. you should explain better your needs

Comment: @scaisEdge my mistake. I have edited it.

Comment: where is stored the value 4A60193390662 ?? in the same  model  or in a related model ..  .. we need to know the $model struct and eventually the struc for related  model that contain the value  4A60193390662 ..

Comment: @scaisEdge its the same model

Comment: which is the field name  ??

Answer (score 1):

Dont know why you are not using the relation here for the meter to display the meter `serial` rather than the `id`.

Easiet way to avoid any further work as you want to just display it, 2 things you need to do

- Assign the value to the input manually via relation.
- Make the field `disabled` to exclude it out of the model collection array. (*in case you use active form for the field*).

I assume you have a relation to the meter in your current model with name `getMeter()` and the number you are trying to display `4A60193390662` is in field `serial_number`. You can change accordingly.

If you havent defined a relation than define one now

```
public function getMeter(){
    return $this->hasOne(Meter::class,['id'=>'meter_id']);
}
```

Although you are using a custom html field you can still use the active form and mark the field disabled so that the activeform wont submit it with the model collection array and there wont be errors when saving the records like

> meter_id should be an integer.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'meter_id')->textInput(['disabled' => 'disabled', 'value' => $model->meter->serial_number]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try add an entry also for the field with value 4A60193390662 eg: $model->meter_name

```
<input type="text" id="the-mter-name" class="form-control col-md-12" value="<?=$model->meter_name?>" />
```

and if you don't want see the entry for meter_id  ..  you could use hidden input for this so mantain the related  avlue for the model loading and popolation

And as suggested in comment by Michal Hyncica (sorry for improper charset  ) you could wrap the input inside a check fo new record

```
<?php
    if(!$model->isNewRecord) {
        echo '<input type="text" id="the-mter-name" class="form-control col-md-12" value="' . $model->meter_name . '" />';
    }
```

Comment: Now its showing me a new text box for `msn` meter serial. I just want to show it while updating

Comment: @Faisal if you want to limit the displaying only for update you can wrap it in `if(!$model->isNewRecord)` condition.

Comment: @Faisal  answer updated for field visible in  update